# Can a program detect it is running in a detached screen?

Tags: gnu-screen

I am running an interactive curses program in a screen session on quite weak hardware. Most of the time, the screen is detached. Is there a way for this program to detect this situation, and basically stop painting on the screen?

Comment: i am just curious: what are some of the reasons you would run a detached screen?

Comment: @foampile If you're never going to detach the screen, what's the point of running within screen at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's an irssi script called [`screen_away`](http://scripts.irssi.org/html/screen_away.pl.html) that sets your away status based on whether or not the screen is attached. It works like this:

Every shell running within a screen will have the [`STY` environment variable](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/screen_20.html) set to the socket name. You can run `screen -ls` to get the path where all the sockets are stored:

```
$ screen -ls

There are screens on:
        11824.pts-24.mmrozek    (Attached)
        2306.ssh        (Detached)
        6615.chat       (Attached)
3 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-mmrozek.
```

Check the execute bit on `/var/run/screen/.../$STY`. If it's set, the screen is attached; otherwise it's detached. You can see from the output above that two of my three screens are attached, and here the corresponding execute bits are set:

```
$ ls -l /var/run/screen/S-mmrozek/

total 0
prwx------ 1 mmrozek mmrozek 0 Oct  5 13:04 11824.pts-24.mmrozek
prw------- 1 mmrozek mmrozek 0 Sep 23 23:45 2306.ssh
prwx------ 1 mmrozek mmrozek 0 Oct  5 12:43 6615.chat
```

You could also just keep checking the output of `screen -ls` for a row that contains `$STY`, and see if it ends in `(Attached)` or `(Detached)`, but that requires running `screen` over and over

Comment: Ha, learned something new today.  Any idea if that execute bit means anything more than just a "attached/detached" flag?